# Whats the best way of sending a lot of parameters between pages?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, parameters, query-string

I have one JSF page and I would like to get to another with a lot of parameters. when I add them to query string by `f:param` at `h:link` it would be very long and unclear, like this:

http://www.example.org/?id1=1&id2=2&id3=3&id4=34324&id5=fdgfrde&id6=434&id7=4324&id7=5543&id8=rewr&id9=fwefe&id10=1021021&id11=retert

what is the best why of sending this parameters between pages?

Comment: Don't see anything bad into that. Try with your current browser, just ask for some long sentence in the address bar and you'll be redirected to google or whatever. If you see the generated query-string you'll notify it's so long. As a (partial) solution for long urls, take a look at prettyfaces.

Comment: If both pages are in the same application you can store parameters in bean on the first page and reuse them on the second.

Comment: If i store parameter in one `@ViewScope` bean and change view to next page i will lose added parameters, that true ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirement, for example which data is not going to chaged frequently those data can be obtained from cookie or view state etc don't forgot to encrypt...

Comment: i don't have code right now... if you want to know more just study about state management(both client side and server side)... http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/492397/State-Management-in-ASP-NET-Introduction

Answer (score 0):

Please learn about the following things then u can get the answer by ur self...

State Management in asp dot net

**Client side**

Hidden Field

View State

Cookies

Control State

Query Strings

**Server side**

Session

Application

for more details

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/492397/State-Management-in-ASP-NET-Introduction